# Docker compose file config

Tags: docker-compose

My docker cli is `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.yml up --build -d`
First `yml` is base file
Second one is `override` for development purpose.

My legacy compose file has strange volume config like this

first `yml` is clear. It makes use of external volume. I have to create volume before hand for docker.

```
volumes:
  static:
    external: true
  media:
    external: true
  scheduler:
    external: true
```

But the second one. What does it mean?

```
volumes:
  static: {}
  media: {}
  scheduler: {}
  pgdata: {}
```

**My docker version**
Docker version 1.12.2, build bb80604, experimental
docker-compose version 1.8.1, build 878cff1
OSX 10.11.6

I have read https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#version-2
But I do not find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "don't use external volumes", have Compose create them.

Comment: Let me try and back to confirm. I am new to docker and feel afraid to break the working program. Thank you :)